# Empty ps_stock in presta 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Is the ps_stock table used in prestashop >1.7 (or it is just for backward compatibility or future option)? I noticed that it is empty and can't find a way to fill it. In presta 1.6 it was filled by Stock management (button Add stock). The reason I'm asking is that I use external report app which uses that table.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually on the Prestashop's roadmap according to discussion with Prestashop's team earlier this year but shouldn't be released soon according to this page : http://build.prestashop.com/howtos/misc/2018-release-schedule/

Comment: Actually, I don't find the answer to my question there.